# How to Install Crystal Report In VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I can't Install Crystal Report on Visual Studio 2010.
I was try many time install it but i was fail every time.

on Visual Studio 2008 inbuilt Crystal Report in toolbox.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio 2010, It does not come inbuilt you need to install it separate.

You can download that from the following link.

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0.exe

See following link where it has explained how to use visual studio 2010.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166291/Generate-a-report-using-Crystal-Reports-in-Visual

Comment: I have already install it(http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0.exe) and

Comment: it was successfully install but still i can't find crystal report in VS 2010. in TollBox crystal report is not exits.

Comment: did you check that code project article and follow same? Also a restart is required. So If you have not restarted it then restart it!

Comment: there create crystalreport.mht file not created .rpt file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501042/cannot-open-rpt-crystal-reports-file-in-visual-studio-2010 this link also

Answer (score 0):

After installing Crystal
1. Open project in VS
2. Click New Project 
3. Ensure you have .Net Framework 4 installed and your project is targeting .Net 4 
4. The Reports should show up in the VS toolbox window.