# No idea what is happen with my project

Tags: vb.net

Since long time ago I have problem with my project that the project changed to kind of binary code and I don't have any idea why this happened to me.

It happened suddenly without any notice from vb.net and it happened sometimes with Crystal Report and sometimes with the form itself.

See the picture:

[image: Error Picture]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the file-type association for .RPT is broken. I saw the pic and you are trying to open the .rpt reports file

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501042/cannot-open-rpt-crystal-reports-file-in-visual-studio-2010). This may solve your problem.