# Visual Studio 2010 not showing crystal report viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I want use crystal reports in my windows application in c# .net.

But when I add a report from add new item and adding a crystal report but the error is that the report is added in ".mht" format not in .rpt format, and also the report viewer also not showing in tool items.

I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate edition.

Comment: Please see if below link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668626/creating-a-crystal-reports-rpt-file-using-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS 2010 crystal report comes separately so you can download crystal report from below link 
[here](http://www54.sap.com/solutions/sme/software/analytics/crystal-visual-studio/index.html)

Comment: Will you please tell me about some thing on my new question.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15040309/1849480)

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reports are not built-in components in Visual studio 2010. You have to download and install it.

If you are interested, you can use ReportViewer instead of Crystal Reports

To download crystal reports, click [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/5264/download-sap-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010-its-fr.aspx)