# Setting predefined size of a page of crystal report for dot matrix printers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I make a application for a Chemist shop , when I print the bill than by default A4 size paper is set for printing that seems to wastage of paper , I want to use dot matrix printer and want to set the paper size 10*6 inch in crystal reports.
I use C# .Net and crystal reports.
Please give some suggestions..

Comment: Have you tried to set paper size in crystal report itself?

Comment: No I have not use this , can we perform this work by it..

Comment: who designs the report?

Comment: Also please share your code where you are calling report

Comment: @AshReva I done this job by page setup option at the design time of crystal reports....

Comment: i added answer from my comment. Can you accept if possible?

Comment: @AshReva please give some suggestion on this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15326485/1849480)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set up paper size at design time when you design crystal report